# 2GIS Api 2.0: как удалить маркер?

Tags: javascript, 2gis-api

Есть маркеры на карте, как сделать так, чтобы при клике удалились какие то определенные? Прошу помочь скрыть первые два маркера.

```
DG.then(function() {
     var map = DG.map('map', {
         center: [54.98, 82.89],
         zoom: 15
     });

     DG.marker([54.98, 82.89]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Я попап!');
     DG.marker([54.97, 82.87]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Я попап!');
     DG.marker([54.97, 82.86]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Я попап!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, в руководстве API 2.0 не выделен метод позволяющий удалять маркеры - **removeFrom()**.

Однако, есть пример, он закопан [здесь.](https://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/ru/examples/markers/#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86)

Таким образом, решение, может быть таким:

Вне объекта DG создаете массив маркеров:

```
var markersArr = [];
```

Объекты-указатели на маркер записываете в массив markersArr:

```
var marker1,marker2;
marker1 = DG.marker([54.98, 82.89]).addTo...
marker2 = DG.marker([54.98, 82.89]).addTo...

markersArr.push(marker1 ,marker2);
```

После наступления нужного вам события, на каждом объекте маркера вызываете метод removeFrom() и очищаете массив:

```
markersArr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    item.removeFrom(map); // map - ваш объект карты
});
markersArr = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявите маркеры через переменные, например, myMarker.
Удалите с помощью стандартного метода [2Gis API](https://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/1.0/manual/markers/#toc-dgmarkerscommon-mhide): `myMarker.hide()`

Comment: Пробовал, не получается, пишет Uncaught ReferenceError: r10 is not defined, переменной не ошибся

Comment: Данное решение подходит только для устаревшего API версии 1.0

Comment: Так погуглите аналог в новой версии апи.

Comment: Уважаемый, я оставил комментарий уточняющий ваш ответ. А что касается вашего последнего комментария, вспоминается анекдот, про еврейский, американский и русский форум. Жаль.

Comment: Не собирался вас обижать, но и отвечать на претензию, ответ на которую легко можно поискать самостоятельно, тоже не собирался.

Comment: Это была не претензия, а *уточнение*. Поэтому и оправдываться не стоило.

Answer (score 0):

создать

```
marker1 = DG.marker([54.98, 82.89]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Я попап!');          
marker2 =  DG.marker([54.97, 82.87]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Я попап!');
```

чтоб удалить

```
marker1.remove(map);                                                        
marker2.remove(map);
```